# $.each with unknown number of JSON results

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json

did a search for this but nothing came up.

I'm currently going through the JSON.net library examples and making real-world scenarios from them. One thing I'm struggling with is looping through the JSON response when I have an unknown number of results.

I know I can create a single-item array by wrapping my parsed JSON object in square brackets if I have one result
eg.

```
$.each([res], function (key, value) {
    //code here
});
```

and not to wrap the object if I have more than one.

How can I make this each call flexible enough to handle both scenarios?

Thanks in advance,
Brett

Comment: You should know the type of the JSON result returned.  If it returns an array, you can loop through it regardless of whether it's empty, contains one element, or more.

Comment: Just write a little helper function that accepts an object and returns an array, if it's already any array just return it, otherwise push it into a new one.

Comment: You should not change the type receive in a function. This is a bad design. Try to avoid it at all cost. (What if you have an array of array, none of the answer below would work). Even if Javascript is a dynamically type language it does not mean that you should do this kind of things. Try to found the spot where it return both type and fix it over there. After that you can assume that `res` is always an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to do it this way, you can type-check your 'res' variable, and only wrap it if it's not. It's not really sexy code, make sure to comment it for legacy, if not wrap it in a isArray() function or something :)

```
$.each((Object.prototype.toString.call(res) === '[object Array]') ? res : [res], function (key, value) {
    //code here
});
```

Edit: as @Klaasman pointed out, you can use jQuery's isArray() function. So it becomes

```
$.each($.isArray(res) ? res : [res], function (key, value) {
    //code here
});
```

Comment: If you're going for this approach, you could use the [jQuery.isArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isArray/) method for type-checking the result

Comment: oh, sure. I don't like to assume people use jQuery usually, but in this case it was obvious from the code. Not paying attention. Will edit accordingly